# Inverse of a tilting module

Tags: derived-categories, tilting

Let $k$ be a field, $A$ an associative unital $k$-algebra, $\operatorname{\mathsf{Mod}} A$ the
category of left $A$-modules and $D^b(\operatorname{\mathsf{Mod}} A)$ the bounded derived category. Let
$A^{\circ}$ be the opposite algebra and $A^e := A \bigotimes_k A^{\circ}$ the enveloping algebra.
Let $T$ be a two-sided tilting complex: $T ∈ D^b(\operatorname{\mathsf{Mod}}  A^e)$.

How can I understand the structure of $T^{\wedge}:=\mathbb{R}\operatorname{Hom}_A(T,A)$, and why is $T^{\wedge} \bigotimes_{A}^{\mathbb L} T \simeq T \bigotimes_{A}^{\mathbb L} T^{\wedge} \simeq A$?

Comment: Could you supply a definition of tilting complex?  

Comment: There are different definitions, for example: Let A be a ring. A tilting complex T over A is an object in Kb(P(A)) which satisfies the following conditions: (I) for all i ≠ 0, the set HomDb(A)(T, T[i]) of homomorphisms in 
Db(A) vanishes, (II) the category add(T) (that is, the full subcategory of all direct sums of direct summands of T inside Kb(P(A))) generates Kb(P(A)) as a triangulated category. By P(A) we denote the additive category of finitely generated projective left A-modules.

Comment: And by Kb(P(A)) the homotopy category of complexes of finite length

Comment: Are you sure the isomorphisms in your final question are correct?  Left tensoring over A by A, oughtn't to do anything at all.  

Comment: Yes, thank you! I've corrected this error.

Comment: Also in my context this tilting complexes induce autoequivalences, so $End_{Db(A)}(T)^{op} \simeq A$

Answer (score 3):

This is explained in [Rickard, Jeremy. Derived equivalences as derived functors. J. London Math. Soc. (2) 43 (1991)], section 4.

An object $X$ in $D^b (\operatorname{\mathsf{Mod}} (A \otimes B^{\mathrm{op}}))$ is called a *two-sided tilting complex* if $$X \otimes^{\mathbb L}_B - \colon D^b (\operatorname{\mathsf{Mod}} B) \rightarrow D^b (\operatorname{\mathsf{Mod}} A)$$ is an equivalence of triangulated categories.

(In the question $A=B$, but I'll ignore that.)

Let $X$ be a two-sided tilting complex. Then by adjointness, $$\mathbb R \operatorname{Hom}_A(X,-) \colon D^b (\operatorname{\mathsf{Mod}} A) \rightarrow D^b (\operatorname{\mathsf{Mod}} B)$$ is also an equivalence of triangulated categories.
There are functorial isomorphisms 
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Hom}_{D^b(\operatorname{\mathsf{Mod}} (A \otimes A^{\mathrm{op}}))}&(X \otimes^{\mathbb L}_B \mathbb R \operatorname{Hom}_A(X,A),-)\\
&\simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{D^b(\operatorname{\mathsf{Mod}} (B \otimes A^{\mathrm{op}}))}(\mathbb R \operatorname{Hom}_A(X,A),\mathbb R \operatorname{Hom}_A(X,-))\\ 
&\simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{D^b(\operatorname{\mathsf{Mod}} (A \otimes A^{\mathrm{op}}))}(A,-),
\end{align}
so $$X \otimes^{\mathbb L}_B \mathbb R \operatorname{Hom}_A(X,A) \\
\simeq A$$ in $D^b(\operatorname{\mathsf{Mod}} (A \otimes A^{\mathrm{op}}))$ by Yoneda's Lemma.

After first proving the isomorphism $$\mathbb R \operatorname{Hom}_A(X,A) \otimes^{\mathbb L}_A X \simeq \mathbb R \operatorname{Hom}_A(X,X \otimes^{\mathbb L}_B B),$$
a similar adjunction gives $$B \simeq \mathbb R \operatorname{Hom}_A(X,A) \otimes^{\mathbb L}_A X$$ in $D^b(\operatorname{\mathsf{Mod}} (B \otimes B^{\mathrm{op}}))$.

Comment: (I realigned one of your equations so that it fits in more screeens :-) )